# how to write left-right join and multiple update query in PHP

Tags: sql, mysql, join

how to construct left-right join and multiple update query in PHP ?

Comment: The same way you do it in pure SQL.

Comment: can you be a little more specific ...

Answer (score 1):

The SQL will not change - your left joins and multiple updates look the same, whether you're writing them as part of a PHP, C# or any other program. If you're looking to learn how to do a left join, look for general SQL tutorials on Google (or maybe ones that are specific to the database you're using).

If you're looking for a generic tutorial for writing SQL inside of php, look here:

http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/4

Specific examples of SQL queries inside of PHP are frequent, here's a left join example:

http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sqljoin/leftJoin.shtml